# Calculating Total Distance Between Way Points android google api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I have develop an application which draws the route between start point and the destination and also user will be able to mark some waypoints along that path and the route will be drawn correctly. But I can only get the distance when I only mark 2 places on the map. If I mark 2, 3 places it will not give me the distance. These are my codes,

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;
    JSONObject jDistance = null;
    JSONObject jDuration = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                /** Getting distance from the json data */
                jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                /** Getting duration from the json data */
                jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                /** Adding distance object to the path */
                path.add(hmDistance);

                /** Adding duration object to the path */
                path.add(hmDuration);
                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }


    return routes;
}


/**
 * Method to decode polyline points
 * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 * */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

}

```
 private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Error downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}



// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        if(result.size()<1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }

        tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }

}
```

> URL I used to request

```
 String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+waypoints;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;
```

[Error I found when I used 4 points with 2 way points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E7FK.png)

This is in onPostExecute method on lines,

```
 double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
 double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
 LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

What I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You Should have to try this by using retrofit.

Put this code on button click in MainActivity:-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TAG1";
    private static final String KEY = "Enter Your Key";
    String displayResponseSource = "";
    String displayResponseDestination = "";
    private Button btn_search;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private APIInterface apiInterface;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompViewSource;
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompViewDestination;
    private String autocompletetextSource = "";
    private String autocompletetextDestination = "";
    private LatLng maplocationdestination;
    private LatLng maplocationsource;
    private double longitudeSource;
    private double latitudeSource;
    private double latitudeDestination;
    private double longitudeDestination;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        autoCompViewSource = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewSource);
        autoCompViewDestination = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewDestination);
        btn_search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        autoCompViewSource.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapterSource(this, R.layout.lv_item));
        autoCompViewSource.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        autoCompViewDestination.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapterDestination(this, R.layout.lv_item));
        autoCompViewDestination.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                autocompletetextSource = autoCompViewSource.getText().toString();
                autocompletetextDestination = autoCompViewDestination.getText().toString();

                apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

                Call<ModelLatLong> call = apiInterface.getResponse(autocompletetextSource, KEY);
//                autocompletetext,KEY
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLatLong>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ModelLatLong> call, Response<ModelLatLong> response) {

                        Log.i("TAG", response.code() + "");

                        ModelLatLong resource = response.body();
                        ArrayList<Results> resultsList = resource.getResults();

                        for (Results results : resultsList) {
                            longitudeSource = results.getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();
                            latitudeSource = results.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
                            Log.i("TAG1", displayResponseSource + "HI");
                        }
                        displayResponseSource = latitudeSource+ "," + longitudeSource;


//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, displayResponseSource, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        maplocationsource = new LatLng(latitudeSource, longitudeSource);

                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(maplocationsource)
                                .snippet(autocompletetextSource)).showInfoWindow();

                        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(maplocationsource, 14);
                        map.animateCamera(center);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ModelLatLong> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.i("TAG1", "Failed");
                        call.cancel();
                    }
                });

                Call<ModelLatLong> calldes = apiInterface.getResponse(autocompletetextDestination, KEY);
//                autocompletetext,KEY
                calldes.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLatLong>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ModelLatLong> call, Response<ModelLatLong> response) {

                        Log.i("TAG", response.code() + "");

                        ModelLatLong resourcedes = response.body();
                        ArrayList<Results> resultsListdes = resourcedes.getResults();

                        for (Results results : resultsListdes) {
                            longitudeDestination = results.getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();
                            latitudeDestination = results.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
                            Log.i("TAG1", displayResponseDestination + "HI");
                        }
                        displayResponseDestination = latitudeDestination + "," + longitudeDestination;

//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, displayResponseDestination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        maplocationdestination = new LatLng(latitudeDestination, longitudeDestination);

                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(maplocationdestination)
                                .snippet(autocompletetextSource)).showInfoWindow();

                        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(maplocationdestination, 14);
                        map.animateCamera(center);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ModelLatLong> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.i("TAG1", "Failed");
                        call.cancel();
                    }
                });

                Call<ModelRoutes> calldistance = apiInterface.getResponseDistance(Get Your Source Latitude and Longitude Here(Eg. 20.9127766,73.7531254), Get Your Destination Latitude and Longitude Here in String(Eg. 23.0098149, 72.5035273), KEY);
                calldistance.enqueue(new Callback<ModelRoutes>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ModelRoutes> call, Response<ModelRoutes> response) {

                        String displayResponse = "";

                        ModelRoutes resourcedis = response.body();
                        Log.i("TAG", response.code() + "Hello");
                        ArrayList<Routes> routesList = resourcedis.getRoutes();
                        for (Routes routes : routesList) {
                            ArrayList<Legs> legsList = routes.getLegs();
                            for (Legs legs : legsList) {
                                String killoMeter = legs.getDistance().getText();
                                double timeDistance = legs.getDistance().getValue();
                                displayResponse += "\n Killometer : " + killoMeter + "\n Time Duration : " + timeDistance + "\n";
                                Log.i("TAG1", displayResponse + "HI");
                            }
                        }


                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, displayResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ModelRoutes> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.i("TAG1", "Failed");
                        call.cancel();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
//        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json");
            sb.append("?key=Enter Your Key Here");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapterSource extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapterSource(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapterDestination extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapterDestination(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

**ModelRoutes.java**

```
public class ModelRoutes extends Legs {

    ArrayList<Routes> routes = null;

    public ArrayList<Routes> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setRoutes(ArrayList<Routes> routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }
}
```

**Routes.java**

```
public class Routes extends Legs{

    ArrayList<Legs> legs = null;

    public ArrayList<Legs> getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }

    public void setLegs(ArrayList<Legs> legs) {
        this.legs = legs;
    }
}
```

**Legs.java**

```
public class Legs  {

    Distances distance;
    Durations duration;

    public Distances getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Distances distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public Durations getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Durations duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public class Distances{
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        String text;
        double value;

    }

    public class Durations{
        String text;
        double value;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

**APIClient.java**

```
public class APIClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**APIInterface.java**

```
public interface APIInterface {
    @GET("/maps/api/geocode/json")
    Call<ModelLatLong> getResponse(
            @Query("address") String str,
            @Query("key") String str2);


    @GET("/maps/api/directions/json")
    Call<ModelRoutes> getResponseDistance(
            @Query("origin") String str,
            @Query("destination") String str1,
            @Query("key") String str2);
}
```

**ModelLatLong.java**

```
public class ModelLatLong extends Results {
    private ArrayList<Results> results=null;

    public ArrayList<Results> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(ArrayList<Results> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

**Results.java**

```
public class Results extends Geometry{
    private Geometry geometry;

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return this.geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }

}
```

**Geometry.java**

```
public class Geometry extends Location{
    private Location location;

    public Location getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

**Location.java**

```
public class Location {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gmapplaceapi.MainActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewSource"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please enter Source place"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewDestination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewSource"
        android:hint="Please enter Destination place"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewDestination"/>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_search"
        tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**lv_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Don't forget to put Internet Permission in manifest file.